# jQuery scrollTo behavior highlighting element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I followed a tutorial on Codepen for a jQuery ScrollTo that I've implemented for a sticky nav in bootstrap 3.

**Issue:**
The page scrolls nicely, but the browser highlights the  it's scrolling to - blue highlight around. See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaredczerew/rf3nL2j8/).

jQuery:

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top -45,
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again

          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jaredczerew/rf3nL2j8/

Comment: are you using Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a Google Chrome issue - I have often seen it on links etc, but this only occurs on Chrome.

add this to your CSS file:

```
.class-name-with-blue-outline {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: just confirmed that it happens in FF and Safari :(

Comment: try this and see if it works - however I can't reproduce the issue, even with your JSFiddle n- could you supply a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I edited my js doing the following to *solve the issue:

- I removed the last six lines that were retargeting (Callback after animation!). This was the key to eliminate the highlighting of the div/element being scrolled to. This led to a new, but easy to fix, problem - the anchor tags in the nav were being highlighted; quick css fix:
- nav li a:focus {
  outline: none;
  }

  // Select all links with hashes
  $('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
   // On-page links
  if (
   location.pathname.replace(/^//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^//, '') 
     && location.hostname == this.hostname
   ) {
    // Figure out element to scroll to
   var target = $(this.hash);
   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
   // Does a scroll target exist?
   if (target.length) {
   // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
   event.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top -45,
   }, 1000, function() {

  ```
   });
  ```

  }
    }
   });

Comment: Apologies, not sure why my js code block doesn't format properly. I tried the { } option,  formatting in code editor,  and pasting and using cntrl + k - all to no avail.